# DataGrid Does Not Show Persian Calendar

Tags: c#, sql, datagrid, ado.net

I want to search between two times. I'm using this code:

```
SqlDataAdapter adap;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT t5 FROM student WHERE t5 BETWEEN '" + label14.Text + "' AND '" + label15.Text + "'", con);
adap = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT t5 FROM student WHERE t5 BETWEEN  '" + label14.Text + "' AND '" + label15.Text + "'", con);

adap.Fill(ds, "t1");
Datagv1.DataSource = ds.Tables["t1"];
```

I get results in the data grid but my problem is that the date time in the data grid is not displayed in the Persian calendar.

Comment: Please don't use string concatenation to construct SQL queries.  They are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (and usually don't perform as well as other approaches).  If you want the SQL in the code then use parameterized queries instead.

Comment: You are aware that the [Persian Calendar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.persiancalendar(v=vs.110).aspx) lives in the `System.Globalization` namespace, yes?